# Finding minor matrices of 3X3 matrix C

Tags: c, matrix

The question I have is how can I take the input of a 3X3 matrix and display all 9 minor matrices. My biggest problem is how can I iterate through all the elements while deleting the specific row and column and then copy the remaining elements into the 2X2 matrix.

Assignment Instructions:

Determine the minor Matrix – M (i,j) for each element (i,j) of the input matrix.
There are 9 elements in the 3X3 input matrix. Hence, there will be 9 minor matrices
generated in this step. The dimension of each minor matrix is 2X2.
Minor matrix of element (i,j) – Delete row i and column j from the original matrix. The
remaining elements form the minor Matrix of element (i,j).
Note that the row and column of the original input matrix need not be actually deleted.
Only keep track of which elements have to be copied into the 2X2 minor matrix from the
original input matrix based on the element indices (i, j).
Declare one 2x2 matrix to store the minor matrix in the main function. Use this matrix
for each of the 9 minor matrices in this step.
Create a function definition which will take the 3X3 original input matrix, element indices
(i,j), and a 2X2 minor matrix as parameters. The function copies the appropriate elements
from the 3x3 matrix into the 2x2 matrix for a given element index (i, j) of the input matrix.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int DET(int matrix[3][3]);

int main() {
int matrix[3][3];
int minor[2][2];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;


printf("Enter 9 elements for a 3X3 matrix.\n");

for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
   for(j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
    printf("Enter element:");
    scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
   for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
     printf(" %d ", matrix[i][j]);
  }
 printf("\n");
}
if(DET(matrix) == 0){
    printf("Matrix is not invertible.\n");
}
else{
printf("The determinant of the matrix is %d\n", DET(matrix));
}

}

int DET(int matrix[3][3]) {

int x, y, z, u, v, w, p, q, r, d;   
  x = matrix[0][0];
  y = matrix[0][1];
  z = matrix[0][2];

  u = matrix[1][0];
  v = matrix[1][1];
  w = matrix[1][2];

  p = matrix[2][0];
  q = matrix[2][1];
  r = matrix[2][2];

  d=x*(v*r-w*q)-y*(u*r-w*p)+z*(u*q-v*p);

  return d; 
}
```

Comment: In order to display a minor number (i0,j0), you need to iterate over the matrix, skipping *if* row is i0 *or* column is j0.  BTW nice DET function. How would you compute a 100x100 matrix determinant?

Answer (score 2):

I think there are many ways to do it. The following is just one example. (maybe inefficient).
I just copied them by saving temporal row and column for minor matrix.

> ```
> void createMinor(int matrix[][3], int minor[][2], int row, int col) {
>     int minor_row, minor_col;
>     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
>         minor_row = i;
>         if (i>row)
>             minor_row--;
>         for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
>             minor_col = j;
>             if (j>col)
>                 minor_col--;
>             if (i != row && j != col)
>                 minor[minor_row][minor_col] = matrix[i][j];
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```